# non-existent class or interface: "Symfony\Config\DoctrineConfig"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to programmatically add an entity-manager, with reference to this documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

However, it needs to be created dynamically, so I'm triggering it by a controller. Unfortunately Symfony does not find the DoctrineConfig class ... although specified as in the docs.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Config\DoctrineConfig;

class AdministrationController extends AbstractController
{


    #[Route('/api/create-org', methods:['POST'])]
    public function setUpNewOrg(DoctrineConfig $doctrine)
    {
        $doctrine->dbal()
            ->connection('test')
            ->url('postgresql://Test:test1234127.0.0.1:5432/testDB')
            ->serverVersion('13')
            ->charset('utf8');
        
        $emNew = $doctrine->orm()->entityManager('test');
        $emNew->mapping('test')
            ->isBundle(false)
            ->type('annotation')
            ->dir('%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity')
            ->prefix('App\Entity')
            ->alias('App');
        
        return $this->json([ 'message' => 'configured' ]);
    }
}
```

However, this leads to following error message:

> Cannot resolve argument $doctrine of
> "App\Controller\AdministrationController::setUpNewOrg()": Cannot
> determine controller argument for
> "App\Controller\AdministrationController::setUpNewOrg()": the
> $doctrine argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or
> interface: "Symfony\Config\DoctrineConfig".

Does this just not work within a Controller?

Symfony version: 6.0.7
PHP version: 8.1.6

Comment: The Config classes (such as DoctrineConfig) are strictly for use in configuration files such as those found under config/packages.  They are automatically generated as part of the config process.  So no, DoctrineConfig will not work in controllers.  Furthermore, config objects just collect config data.  They don't actually do anything.  You seem be trying to configure your own entity manager? That can be trickier than it might originally seem.  Probably want to review why you feel the need for a custom entity manager.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I want to use schemas for each user in a Postgres DB. But those schemas (users) should be generated dynamically and therefore I also need to programmatically create an entity-manager to access those schemas via a separate DB user.

Comment: You can search for `doctrine multi-tenant` for some ideas but the bottom line is that Doctrine is not ideal for these sorts of things.  Or at least I have not found a good solution.

Comment: OK, good to know... so it'd be a better advise to just go with the user id in shared tables?